# How does little endian work on an ASCII string?

Tags: endianness, cpu-architecture

I've read somewhere that ASCII strings aren't affected by endianness, can someone explain this to me?

Comment: See [Memory contents to ASCII string, little endian format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10369625),

Comment: Also related: [Assembly language - Why are characters stored in register as little endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48645360) for a more specific example.